# Sublime Text: any good package for JSP development (jstl & tag lib)?

Tags: jsp, jstl, sublimetext2, frontend, jsp-tags

I am looking for something that makes my life easier when working on JSP pages.

Eclipse provides handy shortcuts, such as:

- JSTL tags autocomplete, ie. `<c`, `<spring` tags below [image: c tag shortcut] [image: spring tag autocompletion]
- JSTL shortcut to relevant tag via `ctrl + left-click`
- Missing JSTL Directives, ie. a missing `<%@ taglib prefix`
- Basic Syntax checking

I can't think of other useful tips but I think you get what tools I am looking for

Comment: Wicket is a web development framework from Apache

Comment: Google Web Toolkit (GWT)

Comment: @VamsiRavi please read the question again, I'm NOT looking for a framework but for a package on Sublime Text.

Answer (score 1):

you can try some simple syntax highlight and autocomplete plugin that you can found here:

[jstl syntax highlight](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JSTL%20syntax)

[JSTL autocomplete](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JSTL%20autocomplete)

actually there is nothing more that this for sublime unfortunally